# Measure : ipython timeit vs timeit method

Tags: python, timeit, python-standalone

the timeit module timeit() method returns the total time, but ipython %timeit returns much more information f.e.

```
 In [17]: %timeit sa.sum()                                                                                                                                                    
 560 µs ± 9.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

is there a standalone %timeit python implementation that you can use in your app ?

---

posted the solution in my [blog](https://myriad.website/timing-code-execution/). thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anything standalone, but this can be easily extracted out of IPython, most of what it does is in the `TimeitResult` class which formats the output https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/8520f3063ca36655b5febbbd18bf55e59cb2cbb5/IPython/core/magics/execution.py#L55-L104

Then there's the nicer reporting of the compile time, worst run being much worse than the fastest, and getting the run number automatically like timeit's cli.

Reusing the code from IPython and python's timeit, and removing some checks that are probably unnecessary for the common use, we can get a simple function to do the timing in the same way IPython does:

```py
import math
import timeit


def _format_time(timespan, precision=3):
    """Formats the timespan in a human readable form"""
    units = ["s", "ms", "\xb5s", "ns"]
    scaling = [1, 1e3, 1e6, 1e9]
    if timespan > 0.0:
        order = min(-int(math.floor(math.log10(timespan)) // 3), 3)
    else:
        order = 3
    scaled_time = timespan * scaling[order]
    unit = units[order]
    return f"{scaled_time:.{precision}g} {unit}"


class TimeitResult(object):
    """
    Object returned by the timeit magic with info about the run.

    Contains the following attributes :

    loops: (int) number of loops done per measurement
    repeat: (int) number of times the measurement has been repeated
    best: (float) best execution time / number
    all_runs: (list of float) execution time of each run (in s)
    compile_time: (float) time of statement compilation (s)
    """

    def __init__(self, loops, repeat, best, worst, all_runs, compile_time, precision):
        self.loops = loops
        self.repeat = repeat
        self.best = best
        self.worst = worst
        self.all_runs = all_runs
        self.compile_time = compile_time
        self._precision = precision
        self.timings = [dt / self.loops for dt in all_runs]

    @property
    def average(self):
        return math.fsum(self.timings) / len(self.timings)

    @property
    def stdev(self):
        mean = self.average
        return (
            math.fsum([(x - mean) ** 2 for x in self.timings]) / len(self.timings)
        ) ** 0.5

    def __str__(self):
        return "{mean} {pm} {std} per loop (mean {pm} std. dev. of {runs} run{run_plural}, {loops} loop{loop_plural} each)".format(
            pm="+-",
            runs=self.repeat,
            loops=self.loops,
            loop_plural="" if self.loops == 1 else "s",
            run_plural="" if self.repeat == 1 else "s",
            mean=_format_time(self.average, self._precision),
            std=_format_time(self.stdev, self._precision),
        )


def nice_timeit(
    stmt="pass",
    setup="pass",
    number=0,
    repeat=None,
    precision=3,
    timer_func=timeit.default_timer,
    globals=None,
):
    """Time execution of a Python statement or expression."""

    if repeat is None:
        repeat = 7 if timeit.default_repeat < 7 else timeit.default_repeat

    timer = timeit.Timer(stmt, setup, timer=timer_func, globals=globals)

    # Get compile time
    compile_time_start = timer_func()
    compile(timer.src, "<timeit>", "exec")
    total_compile_time = timer_func() - compile_time_start

    # This is used to check if there is a huge difference between the
    # best and worst timings.
    # Issue: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6471
    if number == 0:
        # determine number so that 0.2 <= total time < 2.0
        for index in range(0, 10):
            number = 10 ** index
            time_number = timer.timeit(number)
            if time_number >= 0.2:
                break

    all_runs = timer.repeat(repeat, number)
    best = min(all_runs) / number
    worst = max(all_runs) / number
    timeit_result = TimeitResult(
        number, repeat, best, worst, all_runs, total_compile_time, precision
    )

    # Check best timing is greater than zero to avoid a
    # ZeroDivisionError.
    # In cases where the slowest timing is lesser than a microsecond
    # we assume that it does not really matter if the fastest
    # timing is 4 times faster than the slowest timing or not.
    if worst > 4 * best and best > 0 and worst > 1e-6:
        print(
            f"The slowest run took {worst / best:.2f} times longer than the "
            f"fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result "
            f"is being cached."
        )

    print(timeit_result)

    if total_compile_time > 0.1:
        print(f"Compiler time: {total_compile_time:.2f} s")
    return timeit_result


nice_timeit("time.sleep(0.3)", "import time")

# IPython license
# BSD 3-Clause License
#
# - Copyright (c) 2008-Present, IPython Development Team
# - Copyright (c) 2001-2007, Fernando Perez <fernando.perez@colorado.edu>
# - Copyright (c) 2001, Janko Hauser <jhauser@zscout.de>
# - Copyright (c) 2001, Nathaniel Gray <n8gray@caltech.edu>
#
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#
# * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this
#   list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
# * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
#   this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
#   and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
# * Neither the name of the copyright holder nor the names of its
#   contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived from
#   this software without specific prior written permission.
#
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"
# AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE
# IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
# DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE
# FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL
# DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR
# SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER
# CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,
# OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
# OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
```

Comment: that was cool, thanks